# Can the second be the paraphrasing?

Tags: word-choice

1. People dream in colour.
2. People's dreams are coloured.

Do the sentences have the same meaning? Can the second  be the paraphrasing of the first?

Answer (score 1):

The second *can* be a paraphrase of the first, but only loosely.

Example 1 is fairly specific. It means the "viewing" of the dream is in colour, as on a color television or film *as opposed to black and white*.

Example 2 is open to more interpretations.

- The same meaning as Example 1.
- The dreams have some kind of emotional (as opposed to chromatic) cast to them; usually this would be used in a construction like "People's dreams are coloured by the events of the day."
- There is some racial overtone to the dreams ("coloured" is a term used to mean non-white in some circles, and it is deemed offensive in many places)

Comment: I upvoted this, but just wanted to mention that I think the third meaning seems far less likely than the first two. The third seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @J.R.: Agreed. I included it for completeness because it *is* possible.